# Best practice of communicating with instruments using Python

Tags: python, comparative-review

I have seen two different methods - getter and setter method and property - being used in Python libraries which are written for communicating with instruments via VISA commands. An example is given below.

```py
import pyvisa-sim
import pyvisa

# Method 1
class Instument1():

def __init__(self, rsc_addr, rn):
    self._rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager(rm)
    self._rm.timeout = 25000
    self.instr = self._rm.open_resource(rsc_addr)

def get_freq(self):
    return self.instr.query("freq?")

def set_freq(self, freq):
    self.instr.write(f"freq:{freq}Hz")

# Method 2
class Instument2():

def __init__(self, rsc_addr, rm):
    self._rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager(rm)
    self._rm.timeout = 25000
    self.instr = self._rm.open_resource(rsc_addr)

@property
def freq(self):
    return self.instr.query("freq?")

@freq.setter
def freq(self, freq):
    self.instr.write(f"freq:{freq}Hz")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freq = 150*10**9
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager(sim_fpath)
    addr = rm.list_resources()[0]

    inst1 = Instrument1(rsc_addr=addr,rm='@sim')
    inst1.set_freq(freq)
    f1 = inst1.get_freq()

    inst2 = Instrument2(rsc_addr=addr,rm='@sim')
    inst2.freq = freq
    f2 = inst2.freq
```

They both do the job. I personally like the property method more than the getter and setter method because of how concise it is to access the functions. However, widely, people use property for interacting with class variables so I am wondering what people think about this. In addition to this, what can you do if you require an argument for the getter function if using property?

Comment: What are instruments (or "Instument"s) in this context?  What does this program actually _do_?  The title seems to be more about the mechanism (_how_) rather than the purpose (_why_) - can you enlighten us?

Comment: I have been writing a repository [here](https://github.com/christina-chang-tw/PyOctal.git) and I am just curious if the code structure of my repository is good and if there is anyway to improve it further so in this case, I think it is more of a how problem. The instruments here refers to actual testing instruments such as an oscilloscope, multimeter, and as such.

Comment: This will not interpret because your indentation is incorrect. Please fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## conventional spelling

```
class Instument1():
```

Please spell `Instrument` in the usual way.
Also, no need for those extra `(` `)` parens,
as you're not inheriting from anything beyond the default of `object`.

```
    self._rm.timeout = 25000
```

It's not a big deal in this particular case,
but consider spelling it `25_000` to highlight that this
is 25 seconds.
Or consider phrasing it as `25e3` to emphasize
that this is a floating point number of milliseconds,
so values like `float('inf')` would also be acceptable.
Further down within the `if __name__` guard,
you might find it convenient to express `freq` as `150e9`.

---

## document the Public API

```
def __init__(self, rsc_addr, rn):
```

Local variables can be short,
but formal parameters exposed by your Public API
carry a higher documentation burden.
Consider spelling out `resource_addr`
so there's still no need for a """docstring""".

Also, `rn` appears to be a typo for `resource_mgr`.

---

## type hints help with documentation

```
def get_freq(self):
    return self.instr.query("freq?")

def set_freq(self, freq):
    self.instr.write(f"freq:{freq}Hz")
```

Consider adding optional type hints,
which mitigate the need for a """docstring""":

```
def get_freq(self) -> float:
    return self.instr.query("freq?")

def set_freq(self, freq: float) -> None:
    self.instr.write(f"freq:{freq}Hz")
```

Or, IDK, maybe those are actually integer quantities?
As someone calling into your library,
I would wish to resolve such ambiguities.

Maybe the type depends on what kind of resource address the ctor received?
Do you possibly wish to insist on serving just certain types of instruments?
So many questions, so few docstrings.

---

## missing import

```
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager(sim_fpath)
```

I don't know what `sim_fpath` means here.

---

## make method call explicit

```
    f2 = inst2.freq
    time.sleep(0.5)
    f3 = inst2.freq
```

Yeah, I agree with you, this doesn't feel especially natural.
(Despite what my friends over in Ruby land might say.)
We have a volatile quantity that can change on its own.

My concern is that things happen in the real world and on the lab bench,
so the act of reading may take significant time or may have
side effects, we might `raise` an error.
A @property typically will be "safe" and "immediate" to compute,
even if a bit of logging happens while it does that.
It models an internal aspect of the object,
rather than an interaction with the outside world.
The explicit `()` function call of `inst1.get_freq()`
reminds the reader of what's going on.

> what can you do if you require an argument for the getter function if using property?

Yeah, that's just not a good fit.

This is a theoretical question that lacks review context,
so I can't speak to what you had in mind.
So I will make up a question and answer that.

Suppose we could request an average power level observation
that is low or high precision, at a cost of 10 msec or 10 seconds
to make the measurement.

A getter would ask for `inst1.get_avg_power(Precision.LOW)`.

A @property can only ask for `inst2.avg_power`,
so we'll have to encode the precision in either

- a constructor optional keyword argument, or
- a "precision mode select" side effect on the `inst2` that came back

Comment: Thank you, you have clear my doubt on whether to use a setter/getter method or property. I totally agree with your other points as well.

Comment: Hi, I have modified the code based on your review and am wondering if there is anything else that I should add to make the code more robust.

Comment: Please refrain from editing the code in the original question, once an answer has been provided as it may invalidate points made about the original code.

Comment: Great answer, but we generally close theoretical questions.