# Revised: best practice of communicating with an instrument using Python

Tags: python, comparative-review

This is a revised version of the code from the [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286493/best-practice-of-communicating-with-instruments-using-python). It corrects the spelling errors, add in appropriate comments for argument types and doc strings, rewrite number representation, and make the code reproducible by adding in the fake device yaml file. It will be great to get a review how I can improve the code further.

```py
import pyvisa_sim
import pyvisa

# Method 1
class Instrument1():
    """ Instrument1 uses getter and setter method. """

    def __init__(self, rsc_addr, rm):
        self._rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager(rm)
        self._rm.timeout = 25e+03
        self.instr = self._rm.open_resource(rsc_addr, read_termination='\n', write_termination='\n')

    def get_freq(self) -> float:
        """ Get the instrument frequency. """
        return self.instr.query("freq?")

    def set_freq(self, freq: float) -> None:
        """ Set the instrument frequency. """
        self.instr.write(f"freq {freq}Hz")

# Method 2
class Instrument2():
    """ Instrument2 uses property method. """

    def __init__(self, rsc_addr, rm):
        self._rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager(rm)
        self._rm.timeout = 25e+03
        self.instr = self._rm.open_resource(rsc_addr, read_termination='\n', write_termination='\n')

    @property
    def freq(self) -> float:
        """ Get the instrument frequency. """
        return self.instr.query("freq?")

    @freq.setter
    def freq(self, freq: float) -> None:
        """ Set the instrument frequency. """
        self.instr.write(f"freq {freq}Hz")

def main():
    # path to fake object yaml file
    sim_fpath = 'sim_dev.yaml@sim'
    freq = 150e+09 # 150GHz

    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager(sim_fpath)
    # use the first resource that can be found
    addr = rm.list_resources()[0]

    inst1 = Instrument1(rsc_addr=addr,rm=sim_fpath)
    inst1.set_freq(freq)
    f1 = inst1.get_freq()
    print(f1) # this should print out 150e+09

    inst2 = Instrument2(rsc_addr=addr,rm=sim_fpath)
    inst2.freq = freq
    f2 = inst2.freq
    print(f2) # this should print out 150e+09

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

sim_dev.yaml file for fake instrument

```
spec: "1.0"

# devices' specification
devices:
  device 1:
    eom:
      GPIB INSTR:
        q: "\n"
        r: "\n"
    error: ERROR
    dialogues:
      - q: "*IDN?"
        r: "PyOctal,SIM,MOCK,VERSION_1.0"
    properties:
      freq:
        default: 100.0e+09
        setter:
          q: "freq {:.2f}Hz"
        getter:
          q: "freq?"
          r: "{:.2f}"

# different usable resources
resources:
  GPIB::0::INSTR:
    device: device 1
```

Comment: **1.** Why is attribute `_rm` "private" (because of the leading underscore in its name) but attribute `instr` isn't? **2.** Is the `import pyvisa_sim` statement necessary?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
1. I did not think of the logistic of doing that. What I will do is make them both private and have a property class to allow external access to it but prevent alteration of the variables.
2. Yes, as the module handles the fake device response, but it won't be neccessary if the connection is to a real instrument.